# regex named group starting with but not ends with

Tags: python, c, regex

I have two regexes (simplified to be equal)

```
r'^(?P<slug>(^foo)[-\w]+)/$'

r'^(?P<slug>(^foo)[-\w]+)/$'
```

I would to add an exclusion on the first to check for the end so the latter wins.

For example:

`foobar/` should pass the first and never the latter

I want `foobar-my-string/` to fail the first but match the latter

I have tried @sdanzig's answer:

```
r'^(?P<slug>(^foo)[-\w]+(?!my-string$))/$'

r'^(?P<slug>(^foo)[-\w]+)/$'
```

But it doesn't work I always get into the latter with strings that do or do not end with "my-string"

I also tried it the other way around as my regexes are evaluated top to bottom, but it also doesn't work:

```
r'^(?P<slug>(^foo)[-\w]+(my-string$))/$'

r'^(?P<slug>(^foo)[-\w]+(?!my-string$))/$'
```

Comment: I don't understand. You said `foobar/` should pass the first, but `foobar-my-string/` should not pass the first. Can to explain the exact requirement a bit clearly?

Comment: I don't want strings that end with "my-string" to pass the first, I made a typo updated the q

Comment: Do you want 1 regex or 2? And you have removed the `barfoo/` part now. Is that not required?

Comment: Will it fail if you use like this: r'^(?P<slug>(^foo)[\w]+)/$' ?

Comment: No I have two equal regexes but I want to add an "endswith" clause to the first, see the updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this negative lookahead for the second regex because `[-\w]+` is greedy so you end up consuming the entire string even before you trigger the check for negative lookahead.

```
p = r'(?P<slug>(?!.*my-string/$)(^foo)[-\w]+)'
```

Answer (score 2):

Correction... for this particular requirement, you need a look BEHIND assertion, just before the $, to make sure the string doesn't end with my-string/:

```
(foo[-\w\/]+)(?<!my-string\/)$
```

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do with the P... it looks like you want to capture it, optionally?  You could put (?:P)? just before the foo:

```
((?:P<slug>)?foo[-\w\/]+)(?<!my-string\/)$
```